# Map a specific file to a specific MIME-type in Cherokee

Tags: mime-types, cherokee

I want to make my Cherokee serve specific mime-types for my xml files. Now it only gives mimetype application/xml for all xml files.

In apache it is possible to write the following in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

```
<directory dir>
    AddType application/a a.xml
    AddType application/b b.xml
    AddType application/c c.xml
    AddType application/d d.xml
</directory>
```

So that for instance dir/a.xml always get served with content type application/a. Can I do something similar in Cherokee?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **vServers**.
2. Click on the site you want to change.
3. Click the **Behavior** tab.
4. Click **Rule Management**.
5. Click the + (plus) button to add a new rule.
6. Choose **Manual** and select **Full Path** rule type.
7. Type the **HTTP path** which should be */dir/a.xml* and click **add**.
8. Go to the **Handler** tab and select **Static Content**.
9. Go to the **Transform** tab.
10. Under **Header Operations** put ***Content-Type*** for the header and ***application/a*** for the value.

That should do the trick. From there you can save then click on your new rule in the list and click the clone button (beside the add button) and edit it for the other files.

It's a bit tedious but it works. I'm sure it wouldn't be so complicated if you were manually editing the config file but they don't recommend that.

Hope that helps.